# Looking to find the value of this high-power resistor

Tags: power-supply, resistors

I'm trying to find and replace this resistor and I'm having a heck of a time; it seems one of the bands has faded quite a bit.

I'm guessing it's the second band because of how the bands are spaced, so it would be read: red, ?, yellow, brown. I wonder if anyone can help me out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a fuse, it would be helpful to see the surrounding components.

Comment: I'd say 3R9 but could be 3GΩ with 5% tolerance.

Comment: If that resistor has been damaged by heat, the heat may have affected the color paints as well. The last is likely gold. What circuit is this, what does the resistor do in it, and do you have schematics?

Comment: It may also be a fusible resistor.

Comment: I've uploaded another photo of the board.  It's a power supply for a corona discharge ozonator for my hot tub . Thank you so much for the replies much appreciated !!

Comment: Well, whatever the resistor did in the circuit, resistors don't heat up and burn up themselves. The problem is likely elsewhere and the problem causes the resistor to blow up if you replace it with a new one. If you would post a photo of the other side of the PCB as well, we might guess what the resistor did in the power supply and why it blew up.

Comment: updated op to add another photo, thanks again.